# Automate setting up Passive FTP in IIS on Azure Windows Server?

Tags: azure, iis, ftp, windows-server

Is there a way to automate setting up FTP site in IIS on Windows Server? I can manually do that following [this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7#step-1-configure-the-passive-port-range-for-the-ftp-service) But I want to do it using a script.

I'm using IIS 10 on Azure VM running Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Each steps can be automated by relevant PowerShell snippet. Use a search engine and you will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Set up FTP external Firewall IP address and data channel port range, you could apply this script:

```
#Set up data channel
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.ftpServer/firewallSupport" -name "lowDataChannelPort" -value 5000
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.ftpServer/firewallSupport" -name "highDataChannelPort" -value 6000


#Set external firewall support
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/ftpServer/firewallSupport" -name "externalIp4Address" -value "1.1.1.1"
```

There are tons of link about how to build up FTP site with powershell.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Creating-FTP-in-IIS-and-014b8940

You could combine these scripts base on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! The data channel setup was exactly where I was stuck at.